# Implement change detection on plain input elements to run function that updates final result

Tags: angular, typescript

There are up to 12 inputs. Essentially those are the same entities/ objects but with different values. Their integer values directly linked to the resulting value that is shown to a user. As soon as any of the inputs change, there is need to run a function that will update result.
Some suggest hooks `OnChanges()`, others `DoCheck()` and `@Input`. In my case, there is no inheritance between inputs so @Input decorator is unnecessary complexity.... What would be the right way to implement it?

**Example:**

```
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a.x">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a.y">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a.z">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b.x">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b.y">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b.z">

Result: {{result}}


updateResult() {
    result = a.x+a.y+a.z-(b.x+b.y+b.z)
}
```

Comment: I would wrap them in a form and listen for `onValueChanges` on the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a.x" (ngModelChange)="updateResult()">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a.y" (ngModelChange)="updateResult()">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="a.z" (ngModelChange)="updateResult()">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b.x" (ngModelChange)="updateResult()">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b.y" (ngModelChange)="updateResult()">
 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="b.z" (ngModelChange)="updateResult()">
```